# R define function for comparing number of string occurrences between cells in data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, nlp, apply

Generally speaking, I am trying to define a function which will compare the number of occurrences of specified strings per row between two columns, and modify the value of a third column depending on the comparisons outcome.

More specifically, I want a function which corrects the sentiment value of a word if there is a negation in the word which is not in the stem - given that the sentiment value currently in the dataframe is associated with the stem.

Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(word=c("disgraceful","ungrateful","impatient","importantly","undisclosed","disloyal","loyal"), 
             stem=c("grace","grateful","patient","important","disclosed","loyal","loyal"), 
             sentiment=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1))


  word        stem      sentiment
1 disgraceful grace     1
2 ungrateful  grateful  1
3 impatiently patient   1
4 important   important 1
5 undisclosed disclosed 1
6 disloyal    loyal     1
7 loyal       loyal     1
```

Desired outcome after running the newly defined `correct_negation(df,word,stem,sentiment)` function:

```
  word        stem      sentiment
1 disgraceful grace     -1
2 ungrateful  grateful  -1
3 impatiently patient   -1
4 important   important  1
5 undisclosed disclosed -1
6 disloyal    loyal     -1
7 loyal       loyal      1
```

**EDIT**

I have the following now which is working, but failed to put it in a function. It reverses the sentiment if a word has a negation and the stem doesn't (doesn't work for "undisclosed"):

```
negations <- c("dis", "un", "im")

df[["sentiment_adj"]] <- ifelse (
  str_detect(df[["word"]], paste(negations, collapse = "|"))==TRUE &
    str_detect(df[["stem"]], paste(negations, collapse = "|"))==FALSE,
  df[["sentiment"]] * -1, df[["sentiment"]])
```

**EDIT 2**

I managed to get the right sentiments by checking if the extra bits in the word on top of the stem have a negation in them:

```
df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(leftover=paste(unlist(strsplit(as.character(word), split=as.character(stem), fixed=TRUE)),
                     collapse = " "))

df[["sentiment_adj2"]] <- ifelse (
  str_detect(df[["leftover"]], paste(negations, collapse = "|"))==TRUE,
  df[["sentiment"]] * -1, df[["sentiment"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, but unless this is a very specific use-case, I'm sure there's a package out there that will handle this more elegantly:

```
negations <- c("dis", "un", "im")

has_a_negation <- function(words, negations) {
  l_negation <- lapply(words, str_detect, pattern = negations)
  sapply(l_negation, any)
}

has_a_negation(df$word, negations)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

df$sentiment_adj <- ifelse(has_a_negation(df$word, negations),
                           df$sentiment * -1,
                           df$sentiment)

df
#          word      stem sentiment sentiment_adj
# 1 disgraceful     grace         1            -1
# 2  ungrateful  grateful         1            -1
# 3   impatient   patient         1            -1
# 4 unimportant important         1            -1
# 5    disloyal     loyal         1            -1
# 6       loyal     loyal         1             1
```

Comment: it is a rather specific use case, the example I gave is more general. your solution gives the desired outcome for the example set, but if "important" was in the "word" column as well, then it would reverse its sentiment which I don't want. that is the reason I wanted to use str_count

Comment: A "shortcut" could be adding `& as.character(df$word) != as.character(df$stem)` to the `ifelse` statement. `df$sentiment_adj <- ifelse(has_a_negation(df$word, negations) & as.character(df$word) != as.character(df$stem),
                           df$sentiment * -1,
                           df$sentiment)`